# Using Ajax to Post Form Data on change of form field

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am attempting to trigger an interim send of form data when a certain page event occurs, allowing the capturing of the form data in case the user leaves the page. All form data submitted will be compared against a list of completed orders and sorted out by which is complete and which is partial. Would this work to send the session variables off with the form data?

```
<script>
function doAjaxPost() {
var orderSubTotal = '';
var orderTotal = '';
var numOfItems = '';
var items = new Array('');
var ids = new Array('');
var codes = new Array('');
var qtys = new Array('');
var price = new Array('');
var orderTax = '';
var orderShipping = '';
var appliedPromoIdList = '';
var coupon = '';
var storeId = '';
var activeShipPromotionCount = '';
var itemImages = new Array('');
var custEmail = '';
var custFName = '';
var custLName = '';
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "interim-cart-viewer.php",
    data: "",
    error: function (e) {
        alert('Error: ' + e);
    }
});
} document.getElementById("billing-email").on("change", doAjaxPost()); </script>

<strong>
Email Address:</strong>
<input type="text" class="text" name="miscDS.shopperEmailAddress" id="billing-email" size="40" maxlength="99" value=""  />
```

Comment: why do you need so much empty variables ?

Comment: They are filled from shopping cart data, I did not put any information in as test data but I can if it helps.